# Issue with DJI SDK gradle 4.4.0, provided keyword in gradle not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, dji-sdk

Previously my gradle used to look like this and worked fine (apart from few registered bugs)

```
implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.3.2'
```

Now, after changing to

```
implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.4.0'
```

the Camera and other files cannot be recognized anymore. I am attaching a screenshot of the unrecognized imports.

[image]
[image]

However when I am trying to add

```
//dji-drones-sdk
    implementation 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.4.0'
    provided 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.4.0'
```

I am getting "could not download dji-sdk-provided.jar"
Screenshot attached

[image]

All the examples and github codes are in version 4.3.2. Can anyone help me out?
Here is the [link](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) to the dji sdk

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. After Gradle 3.4, the "provided" is replaced by "compileOnly"
I quote,

> Gradle adds the dependency to the compilation classpath only (it is not added to the build output). This is useful when you're creating an Android library module and you need the dependency during compilation, but it's optional to have present at runtime. That is, if you use this configuration, then your library module must include a runtime condition to check whether the dependency is available, and then gracefully change its behavior so it can still function if it's not provided. This helps reduce the size of the final APK by not adding transient dependencies that aren't critical. This configuration behaves just like provided (which is now deprecated).

Hence using **compileOnly** in place of **provided** will do the trick.

Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) to the gradle changes documentation